# Improperly highlighted when used with cursorcolumn

Tags: syntax-highlighting, cursorline

With this minimal `.vimrc` I get a highlight conflict in several situations.

```
set nocompatible
set runtimepath +=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim

filetype off
call vundle#begin()
    Plugin 'itchyny/vim-cursorword'
    Plugin 'lfv89/vim-interestingwords'
    Plugin 'w0ng/vim-hybrid'
call vundle#end()

filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
syntax on

set cursorcolumn
set termguicolors

set background=dark
colorscheme hybrid
```

When the cursor is on a brace, the matching brace is improperly highlighted (`showmatch`):

[image: brace]

When the cursor is on `foo` the other corresponding functions are improperly highlighted (`itchyny/vim-cursorword`):

[image: foo]

When using the plugin `lfv89/vim-interestingwords` and the cursor is on a highlighted word:

[image: highlight word]

As this issue appears with different plugins, I would like to understand the cause and find a way to solve it:

The context about this issue is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 22:32:42)
Included patches: 1-1829
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):

$ mintty --version
mintty 2.7.6 (x86_64-px-cygwin)
```

I encounter the same issue with `xterm`:

[image: xterm]

Comment: On macvim with solarized but w/o vim-interestingwords and vim-hybrid, all is OK. Same with vim-interestingwords, but w/o vim-cursorwords: colors OK, but no highlight. Same with vim-cursorwords and vim-hybrid, but w/o vim-interestingwords, all is OK. You should add more context to your question, which platform/terminal are you using? You seem to be on Windows, but also on Ubuntu? Your troubles could come from a limited terminal; the colorscheme you are using has the requirement `Vim 7.3+ on Linux and Mac, using a terminal that supports 256 colours.`, So my guess, the culprit is your terminal.

Comment: Did you set the environment variable `TERM` to `xterm-256color` or similar in your terminal?